# Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1 (same version)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

so I ran into the following problem:

`Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1`

Says Heroku when I deployed my app. This error should only happen when you have a mismatch with your current ruby version and your Gemfile's ruby version.

You can see any code [here](https://github.com/chatisto/chatisto)

Here's the build output:

```
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.1
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
remote:        Old: ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-linux]
remote:        New: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1
remote:        Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to chatisto.
remote:
```

What's causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

woooooow, nasty fail.

Found the problem:

I read the ruby version out of the `.ruby-version` as rbenv generates this file when executing `rbenv local 2.3.1`
. This file had a break after the version number. (Fixed it [here](https://github.com/chatisto/chatisto/commit/5e4887db4a59ca0fc252b54d4a23de18e9917d13))

I used this code to read it:

```
ruby_version_file = File.expand_path(".ruby-version", __dir__)
ruby File.read(ruby_version_file)
```

While `File.read(ruby_version_file)` returned `"2.3.1\n"`... But in the heroku build log this was really hard to see.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error, but in different context, in the Jenkins build automation. In my case the solution was to call the:

```
rbenv rehash
```

after calling the existing line of code: `rbenv local 2.3.1`